# How to start a conversation using an event in Dialogflow cx sending by python

Tags: python, dialogflow-cx

I'm trying to start a conversation from dialogflow cx python API. I have seen this question [Start a conversation at the beginning of a flow using flow ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65241848/start-a-conversation-at-the-beginning-of-a-flow-using-flow-id) that solves the problem using Node.js but I'm not able to replicate in python.
In my code I have:

```
text_input = session.TextInput(text=msg)
query_input = session.QueryInput(text=text_input, language_code=language_code)
request = session.DetectIntentRequest(session=session_path, query_input=query_input)
response = session_client.detect_intent(request=request)
```

I would like to change session.TextInput() to session.EventInput, for example, as [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/EventInput) but it does not work with dialogflow CX and the library dialogflowcx_v3beta1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an event as query_input, you should use type [EventInput()](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow-cx/latest/dialogflowcx_v3/types.html#google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3.types.EventInput) in your [QueryInput()](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow-cx/latest/dialogflowcx_v3/types.html#google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3.types.QueryInput). See code below on how to implement it.

```
from google.cloud import dialogflowcx_v3beta1 as dialogflow
from google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3beta1 import types

import uuid

project_id = "your-project"
location = "us-central1" # my project is located here hence us-central1
session_id = uuid.uuid4()
agent_id = "999999-aaaa-aaaa" # to get your agent_id see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65389964/where-can-i-find-the-dialogflow-cx-agent-id
session_path = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/agents/{agent_id}/sessions/{session_id}"


api_endpoint = f"{location}-dialogflow.googleapis.com"
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
client = dialogflow.services.sessions.SessionsClient(client_options=client_options)

event = "custom_event"
event_input = types.EventInput(event=event)
query_input = types.QueryInput(event=event_input,language_code="en-US")
request = types.DetectIntentRequest(
        session=session_path,query_input=query_input
        )
response = client.detect_intent(request=request)

print(response.query_result.response_messages[0])
```

Custom event:

[image]

Output using the [custom event created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65241848/start-a-conversation-at-the-beginning-of-a-flow-using-flow-id):

[image]

Comment: Hi Ricco, I'm having issues with from google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3beta1 import types. Despite having Pip installed google-dialogflow-cx, I'm getting errors saying the import statement can't be resolved?