# google-cloud-dialogflow-cx: Cannot resolve "google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3" import "types" statement

Tags: python, dialogflow-cx

I am currently trying to import `types` from `google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3` through the google-cloud-dialogflow-cx library as follows:

```
from google.cloud import dialogflowcx_v3 as dialogflow
from google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3 import types
```

The second line of code is giving me the error:

> from "google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3" import types could not be resolved

On VSCode despite having `google-cloud-dialogflow-cx` installed. Has anyone run into this problem before?

(I am hoping to use the following code from this thread after I can get the second line of code to work: [How to start a conversation using an event in Dialogflow cx sending by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71130572/how-to-start-a-conversation-using-an-event-in-dialogflow-cx-sending-by-python))

Comment: Can you try adding the import statements as `from google.cloud import dialogflowcx_v3beta1 as dialogflow` and `from google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3beta1 import types`? Let me know it's helpful or not?

Comment: Hi @Nate, Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?