# How to send a reminder from chatbot in Dialogflow CX?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

Session in Dialogflow CX ends after 30 minutes and I'd like to send reminder to the end user after 20 minutes to answer the question. Can I do it in Dialogflow CX interface or it's only possible in my code? But then how do I detect intent of not responding?

Comment: I think this is possible with the Dialogflow CX client libraries. Are you currently using any client libraries?

Comment: I'm using python-dialogflow-cx client library https://github.com/googleapis/python-dialogflow-cx

Comment: Can you update the question with the code where the `detect_intent` request is made? How are you constructing the text input? And what sort of reminder are you trying to send to the user?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are able to keep a track of the time that has passed (i.e. a certain amount of time has passed), you can define a custom event for that flow and then trigger that custom event via a `detectIntent` request. Check out a similar approach over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65241848/start-a-conversation-at-the-beginning-of-a-flow-using-flow-id).

I also suggest that waiting 20 minutes for an answer is probably indicating something towards designing an alternative experience. If its an IVR based bot, you could possibly look at the [No Speech Timeout setting](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent#settings-speech) and then utilizing the no-input-default, no-input-1/2/3 events that get fired too.